# Из-за чего возникает ошибка 299 в данной программе при использовании ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: c++, windows, память, процесс

```
    DWORD pid;
HWND hForeground = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hForeground, &pid);
const int MAX_SIZE = 512;
char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
while (true) {
    int l = 10;
    cout << l << endl;
    if (ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)&l, buffer, sizeof(l), 0) == 0 && GetLastError() == 299)
        cout << "paging file"<<buffer << endl;
    else if (ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)&l, buffer, sizeof(l), 0) !=0)
        cout << "RAM" << endl;
    cout << l << endl;
    Sleep(100);
    system("CLS");
}
```

по моей задумке программа должна получать ячейку памяти занимаемую переменной **l** и если она есть в оперативной памяти то выводится **RAM**, и соответственно если ее там нет то значит она в файле подкачки. Но почему-то происходит ошибка 299 и buffer не заполняется.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вы пытаетесь получить хендл собственного процесса? Зачем тогда понадобилось вся эта возня с `GetForegroundWindow()`, если хендл своего процесса можно сразу получить через `GetCurrentProcess()`? Зачем вы пытаетесь сделать `OpenProcess` на свой собственный процесс? Он для вас и так "open". И, наконец, откуда вы взяли это `299`? С чего вы взяли, что чтение валидного региона адресного пространства процесса может завешиться неуспешно? И с чего вы взяли, что это имеет какое-то отношение к "paging file"?

Comment: В операционной системе с виртуальной памятью на уровне пользователя нет понятия "RAM" вообще. На уровне пользователя не существует никакого способа отличить виртуальную память "в RAM", от виртуальной памяти "не в RAM". Почему вы решили, что `ReadProcessMemory` как-то позволить вам увидеть это различие? `ReadProcessMemory` читает виртуальную память. Он ничего не знает ни про какой "RAM". Он про "RAM" и слыхом не слыхивал.

Comment: Это уже не говоря о том, что `l` - это стековая переменная. Не представляю себе ситуации, чтобы система вытеснила в файл подкачки стек работающей программы.